# Wiki Documentation With Permissions

Tags: wiki, documentation, mediawiki

So I've set up a MediaWiki for managing some docs, we have AD integration set up and so far things are going fine...

But wow is managing permissions a pain in the butt! Requires editing LocalSettings every time, so as we add new sections I have to write PHP, bleh.

Anyone know of any wiki derivatives that support in-browser editing of permissions (by namespace would be fine, also, the ability to edit namespaces in the browser is a must!). I'd like to keep the ability to support wiki plugins (syntax, templates, AD integration and stuff).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're running with [Confluence from Atlassian](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview) now (makers of Bitbucket), 10 users (cheap), it gets expensive fast after that though. :(

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to AD integration (though I believe it supports AD) but I would strongly suggest Dokuwiki. It allows you to manage permissions, users, etc using the interface. It also can be configured to use a variety of database solutions or it can use flat files in the directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

We're successfully using foswiki at work. Check it out. Free and flexible, permission management like you ask for and lots lots more.

Read about it at: http://foswiki.org/